# While statement not evaluating to false for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm migrating a test I wrote in the Selenium IDE to Python WebDriver and I'm having some issues with a **'while'** loop scenario.  Here's the IDE code:

```
while | selenium.isElementPresent("xpath=//select[@name='servers']/option")
   storeValue | //select[@name='servers']/option | myServerIP
   waitForElementPresent | name=servers
   addSelection | name=servers | ${myServerIP}
   waitForValue | //input[@value='Delete'] | Delete
   clickAndWait | //input[@value='Delete']
   waitForNotText | //select[@name='servers']/option | ${myServerIP}
endWhile
```

I have a box that contains addresses of time servers that have been entered (i.e. 129.6.15.30, time-d.nist.gov, etc..).  While addresses are listed in the server list box, the object **"//select[@name='servers']/option"** exists.  Once all the servers have been deleted, the object is no longer in existence.

While the server list object exists..

- Stores the name of top server in the list.
- Selects that server.
- Deletes that server from the list
- Confirms that server name has been removed from the list

As I'm trying to migrate this scenario over to WebDriver, I'm having some issues.

```
while expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located("//select[@name='servers']/option"):
   myServerIP = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='servers']/option").text
   assertExpectedConditionTrue(driver, "By.NAME", "servers")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='servers']/option[contains(text(), '"+ myServerIP + "')]").text
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='servers']/option[contains(text(), '"+ myServerIP + "')]").click()
   assertExpectedValueConditionTrue(driver, "By.XPATH", "//input[@value='Delete']", "Delete")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Delete']").click()
   assertExpectedConditionFalse(driver, "By.XPATH", "//select[@name='servers']/option", myServerIP)
```

The server names are found and deleted just fine.  However, the 'while' part never seems to evaluate to being invisible, which causes a **NoSuchElementException** failure (on the first line in the 'while' loop) once all the server names are removed.  I'm looking for a way to make the 'while' loop evaluate to false so it's exited gracefully once all the server names have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `while True` loop and exit the loop once you get a `TimeoutException`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='servers']/option")))
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    # rest of the code
```

Or, alternatively, catch `NoSuchElementException`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        myServerIP = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='servers']/option").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

---

Additionally, `selenium` has this [`Select` class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) which makes it easy to work with `select->option` HTML blocks:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("servers"))
select_by_visible_text(myServerIP)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @alecxe.  I gave this a try & it failed for the same reason as before at the same line as before `myServerIP = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='servers']/option").text`.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe.  You always seem to have a solution :-).

Comment: I knew about the 'Select' option.  I'm not really sure why I hadn't used that instead as it is easier.